# How to add an icon in navigation bar for navigation page in xamarin forms for android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

I have made simple navigation pages.
Now I want to add icon for android in navigation bar.

I added an screenshot and highlighted with black circle where i want to add an icon.
[image]

I also tried custom renderer.
That is provided answer from this post: [Change icon on Navigation bar - Xamarin.Forms Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048224/change-icon-on-navigation-bar-xamarin-forms-android)

But not worked for me.
Here it is

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change icon on Navigation bar - Xamarin.Forms Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048224/change-icon-on-navigation-bar-xamarin-forms-android)

Comment: Not worked for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace XamarinFormsMaps.Droid
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var bar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)typeof(NavigationPageRenderer)
            .GetField("_toolbar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(this);
            bar.SetLogo(Resource.Drawable.icon);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this one!

Comment: Can u provide me the references names that i have to import for this code?

Comment: Are you using FormsAppCompatActivity ? If so then you can just copy paste the code and change the namespace alone to your project namespace and this should work.

Comment: **var bar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)typeof(NavigationPageRenderer)
                .GetField("_toolbar", BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .GetValue(this);** At this line visual studio showimg me an error **"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** And I don't know what is FormsAppCompactActivity.. And I didn't set any icon till now.. You can see it in my question's screenshot...

Comment: Am sorry i was using my extension lib for the reflection which might have caused issue, i have updated the code i think now it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't used it but I guess you are looking for this:

```
NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon (this, "image.png");
```

This will set the title Icon in Xamarin Forms.
If you want to change the back button Icon, hamalaiv gave you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048224/change-icon-on-navigation-bar-xamarin-forms-android) link

Comment: I tried NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon but I don't understand where to put this code.. And also don't understand how to put path of image in code... And I also tried that link suggestion which one you provided but its not working I don't know what's the problem.. But you can see that in my 2nd screenshot in my question...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dilmah.

It work for me.
With Xamarin.Forms 2.5, I change the constructor by

```
public CustomMapRender(Context context) : base(context)
```

to avoid warning of obsolete constructor.