# How to set Icon of Page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try set Icon for my Pages in Xaml:

```
Icon="icon.png
```

But it's not working, so I found other solution: [How to add an icon in navigation bar for navigation page in xamarin forms for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466050/how-to-add-an-icon-in-navigation-bar-for-navigation-page-in-xamarin-forms-for-an)
It's custom render and working:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace XamarinFormsMaps.Droid
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var bar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)typeof(NavigationPageRenderer)
            .GetField("_toolbar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(this);
            bar.SetLogo(Resource.Drawable.icon); //how to load other icon, when Page is changing?
        }
    }
}
```

But I want set other Icon for other Pages... It's code set the same Icon for all pages. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be notified when the current page of Navigation is changed by using below code.
It's a method in NavigationPageRenderer.

```
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentPage")
        {
            var page = Element.CurrentPage as ContentPage;
            if (page != null)
            {
                //do what you want.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to set Icon property on the NavigationPage Class in xaml? I think that it might be for the NavigationPage instance.

Comment: I try NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon, navigationPage.Icon = "icon.png", but not working...

Comment: Hm.. Then it might be that it's not supported on the Navigation bar but its icon property is just for TabbedPage. At least the icon shows on the tabbar if you use TabbedPage.